# how to concatenate a string by adding prefix and postfix with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
Anion Gap
Body Surface Area (BSA)
Creatinine Clearance
Stack Overflow
```

i want to add "String" Before Text and "String" after end of text.

I have Following expression which runs perfectly in excel:-

=CONCATENATE("",B1,"")

Output:-

```
<string>Anion Gap</string>
<string>Body Surface Area (BSA)</string>
<string>Creatinine Clearance</string>
<string>Stack Overflow</string>
```

from above ,can anyone please help me out.I want the user interface code (html format) in which it should accept a excel file from the user or textarea box where User can place his text,  and then apply this code and generate it as shown in output.

Comment: What is your current solution?

Comment: Why the python flag? It seems not python related.

Comment: It would nice to provide a small example. Its easier to debug and to find a solution. Later that solution can be applied to your entire problem.

Comment: i used to copy this numbering in excel column, and then in another column ,i used to apply that expression and then drag it up to the last list numbering,it would automatically generate the list

Comment: I wrote the python function for fun: `map(lambda x: "<string>{}{}</string>".format(x, '.0' * (3 - x.count('.'))), somestring.split("\n"))`. If you want a javascript version as well, please try something yourself first and we can help you from there. :)

Comment: Your concatenate formula might be a little more readable like `="<string>"&A1&REPT(".0", 3-(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", ""))))&"<string>"`.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. The title is "how to convert excel expression into a javascript or jquery code", but you don't mention JS/jQuery anywhere, and there are no tags either. What's the deal? Do you still need the JavaScript code?

Comment: actually I have expression in excel. and i want that expression to be converted into javascript code.

Comment: @ joel thanks for your python script,but how can I use that script.i have to place all the content in text file or excel?????

can you please tell me

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here's some JavaScript code that will generate the output you need:

`pad` is a recursive function that generates any required trailing zeros.

```
function pad(num, diff) {
    return diff > 0 ? pad(num, diff - 1) + 0 : num;
}
```

`processString` does the bulk of the work. Note that this code only works on single digit numbers as per your question. ie it wouldn't work on `1.12.1` properly, for example.

```
function processString(num) {

    // remove any existing dots
    var tmp = num.replace(/\.+/g, '');

    // calculate the difference between the desired length of the string
    // and the current string
    var diff = 4 - tmp.length;

    // generate a template
    var tmpl = '<string>#{padded}</string>';

    // if the diff is greater than zero return the padded string
    // with the dots added back in otherwise return the original string
    var padded = diff > 0 ? pad(tmp, diff).split('').join('.') : num;
    return tmpl.replace('#{padded}', padded);
}
```

Then, of course, you need to add the textarea to your page:

```
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

And some additional JavaScript to grab the text added and convert it:

```
function processArea() {
    var area = document.getElementById('area');

    // split the text at each carriage return
    var arr = area.value.split(/\n/);

    // loop over each string and process it
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
      arr[i] = processString(arr[i]);
    }

    // repopulate the text area with the output
    area.value = arr.join('\r\n');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/12/)

If, on the other hand, you need to account for numbers with multiple digits, replace the above two functions with these:

```
function pad(num) {
    if (num.length < 4) {
      num.push('0');
      pad(num);
    }
    return num;
}

function processString(num) {
    var tmp = num.split('.');
    var diff = 4 - tmp.length;
    var tmpl = '<string>#{padded}</string>';
    var padded = diff > 0 ? pad(tmp).join('.') : num;
    return tmpl.replace('#{padded}', padded);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hbq7bdL6/3/)

Comment: Also now i want to convert same to the text,then is it possible?

Comment: @ Andy, how to work on multiple digits then?? If i have the string like: 1.12.25.0

Comment: Edited answer to show how to use multiple digits @ShrinathDhatrak.

Comment: @ Andy

Great Job Sir ji..

Really it works for Single as well as Multiple digits

really you deserve 1000000000000* repution..